# Regular expression to find "can t", "haven t" and etc. and add apostrophe back

Tags: java, regex

I need to process some sentences which miss apostrophe.

For example:

1. item is a fake. seller claims **it s** genuine and it **isn t**
2. **it s** fake and has no photo you **can t** see marlin, sent it back awaiting refund.

How do I use a regular expression to find "doesn t", "can t", "haven t", "aren t", "it s" and etc.

Note:

"it s" and "can t" might be tricky here.

For example:

"I **can t**ell a story" v.s. "I **can t** do anything now"

We shouldn't add apostrophe in the first sentence

Comment: You use the word boundaries to tackle the tricky cases: `string.replaceAll("\\bcan t\\b", "can't")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than trying to do regex olympics here, I would recommend that you just replace each broken contraction with its corrected replacement.  You can define a map, which maps each broken contraction to its replacement.  Then, iterate over that map and apply each correction to the text you want to correct.

```
String input = "I can t do it because it s not raining and it doesn t make sense.";
Map<String, String> cnts = new HashMap<>();
cnts.put("doesn t", "doesn't");
cnts.put("can t", "can't");
cnts.put("haven t", "haven't");
cnts.put("aren t", "aren't");
cnts.put("it s", "it's");
cnts.put("isn t", "isn't");
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : cnts.entrySet()) {
    String start = entry.getKey();
    String end = entry.getValue();
    input = input.replaceAll("\\b" + start + "\\b", end);
}
System.out.println(input);
```

**Output:**

```
I can't do it because it's not raining and it doesn't make sense.
```

Comment: Using HahsMap is really smart. Thanks!

Comment: Can tears pain to can'tears pain.

Comment: @PeterRader Nope, that won't happen because my regex looks for a word boundary on either side of `Can t`.

Comment: Not technically needed here, but you should use [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) and [`Matcher.quoteReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Good simple solution, but if input is a very long string, and/or number of words to replace is large, you'd want to change to an algorithm that only processes the string once, e.g. [using `appendReplacement`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43062603/5221149).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than performing multiple [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) calls, do it all in a single iteration of the text by writing a replacement loop, using [`appendReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) and [`appendTail()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail-java.lang.StringBuffer-).

To prevent tricky cases like "I can tell a story", use the [`\b` word-boundary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds) construct, which in a Java string literal is `"\\b"`.

You would also want the regex to be case-insensitive, so both `don t` and `Don t` gets fixed. This can be done with the [`CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flags, which can alternatively be given in the regex as `(?i)`.

```
private static String fixApostrophe(String input) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(input.length());
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b(?:aren t" +
                                         "|can t" +
                                         "|doesn t" +
                                         "|haven t" +
                                         "|isn t" +
                                         "|it s" +
                                         ")\\b").matcher(input);
    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(buf, m.group().replace(' ', '\''));
    return m.appendTail(buf).toString();
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(fixApostrophe("item is a fake. seller claims it s genuine and it isn t"));
System.out.println(fixApostrophe("it s fake and has no photo you can t see marlin, sent it back awaiting refund."));
System.out.println(fixApostrophe("I can tell a story"));
System.out.println(fixApostrophe("I can t do anything now"));
```

*Output*

```
item is a fake. seller claims it's genuine and it isn't
it's fake and has no photo you can't see marlin, sent it back awaiting refund.
I can tell a story
I can't do anything now
```

Comment: I've never even _seen_ a lot of what you are doing.  This is worth studying once or twice +1.

Answer (score 1):

How about this regex?

```
\bcan t\b
```

Then you can replace the space.

You can build regex for other words similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Well let's try with a little regex olympics here :)

```
replaceAll("(don|is|isn|hasn|haven)(?: +)(\\b[s,t]\\b)", "\\1'\\2")
```

like

```
String text = "I don t like what hasn t been written";
text.replaceAll("(don|is|isn|hasn|haven)(?: +)(\\b[s,t]\\b)", "\\1'\\2");
```

Output:

> I don't like what hasn't been written

Disclaimer: didn't run the code, it might contain syntax errors (though it shouldn't).

Now you could generate the part

```
(don|is|isn|hasn|haven)
```

programatically to include all cases that need to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

More generic (not sure if you want it that generic):

```
yourText.replaceAll("(\\w+) (\\w)\\b", "\\1'\\2");
```

This will work for any `something x`: one or more word-letters (`something`) followed by a space and a single word-letter (`x`).

Parentheses introduce groups that can be referred in the substitution expression by using \i (i is the number of the group, starting on the left with 1).

\w is any word letter
\W is any non-word letter
+ is one or more occurrences

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: Can you tell anything about your concern?

Comment: I gave you'a problematic example, if you look closely.